# Image stored in MySQL shows up on every page but I only need it 1 page

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, image

Oke I am developing a website using ASP.NET and VB. I'm also using webfroms for the pages and a masterpage for the layout.

Now I want to store the image path of my products in MySQL database and retrieve these images on pageload. But when i write the code in a specific page it still shows up on EVERY page linked in the website.

This code is only written in 1 of my webform pages (In the Pageload SUB), yet it shows up in all of them or I get an error where there is no imagebutton with the ID ImageButton1.

It is being called in a webform as an image so:
and when the VB.NET code runs on page load it is suppose to change the ImageButton1 ImageUrl to the path stored in the mysql Database.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Text="" />
```

This is my code:

```
Private Sub ImageDisplay()
    Dim QueryStr As String

    _conn = New MySqlConnection
    _conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ProductConn").ConnectionString
    Dim _reader As MySqlDataReader

    _conn.Open()

    QueryStr = "SELECT Image FROM products.items WHERE Type = 'Suit'"
    _cmd = New MySqlCommand(QueryStr, _conn)
    _reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If _reader.Read Then
        Dim path = _reader.GetString(0)
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = path
    Else

    End If

    _conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: This function does not tell us the context in which it is being called. Will you post the markup and some other code that is callign this function?

Comment: This is how i am using it *see edit*. please let me know how iam able to make it clearer.

Comment: is that `ImageButton` on master page.

Comment: No, it's on a blank web page connected to a masterpage.

Comment: This should not cause issue. just check if `ImageDisplay` is called from some shared code (like some function in `MasterPage`). Otherwise this is fine.

Comment: Wel I don't know whats the problem but i found a workaround for it. In the page load I added an if statement that    If request.rawurl = *the specific page, then it will load the image and it works. Thank you.

Comment: I have another question, in this database I have multiple image path stored, that all have to be displayed in a specific ImageButton, how do i go to the next record? I can only display the first image that is stored in the database with the code above.

Comment: Best option is to have a grid or repeater that put as many buttons as the number of records you get from database. So if you have 10 images (10 records) you get 10 rows in repeater or grid with 10 buttons.